# MonoTouch, drawing a cropping region layer over a UIImageView

Tags: ios, image, xamarin.ios, core-graphics, crop

In our app we'd like to be able to crop, scale and pan an image, and I just can't seem to figure out how I am supposed to draw a cropping region on top of my UIImageView.

I tried messing with coregraphics, I could render a region with a black stroke on my image, but the image would flip. Not only that, but since I had drawn ON the image, I'm afraid that if I were to move and scale it using gestures, the region would be affected too!

A push in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Heres my code that doesen't really do what I want, to show some research effort.

```
        // Aspect ration - Currently 1:1
        const int arWidth = 1;
        const int arHeight = 1;

        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(ImgToCrop.Frame.Size);

        var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

        // Set the line width
        context.SetLineWidth(4);
        UIColor.Black.SetStroke();

        // Our starting points.
        float x = 0, y = 0;

        // The sizes
        float width = ImgToCrop.Frame.Width, height = ImgToCrop.Frame.Height;

        // Calculate the geometry
        if(arWidth == arHeight){
            // The aspect ration is 1:1
            width = ImgToCrop.Frame.Width;
            height = width;

            x = 0;
            y = ImgToCrop.Frame.GetMidY()-height/2;

        }

        // The rect
        var drawRect = new RectangleF(x,y,width,height);

        context.DrawImage(new RectangleF(
            ImgToCrop.Frame.X,
            ImgToCrop.Frame.Y,
            ImgToCrop.Frame.Width,
            ImgToCrop.Frame.Height),ImgToCrop.Image.CGImage);

        // Draw it
        context.StrokeRect(drawRect);
        ImgToCrop.Image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help you:

```
    public static UIImage ScaleToSize (UIImage image, int width, int height)
    {
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (new SizeF (width, height));
        CGContext ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();
        float ratio = (float) width / (float) height;

        ctx.AddRect (new RectangleF (0.0f, 0.0f, width, height));
        ctx.Clip ();

        var cg = image.CGImage;
        float h = cg.Height;
        float w = cg.Width;
        float ar = w / h;

        if (ar != ratio) {
            // Image's aspect ratio is wrong so we'll need to crop
            float scaleY = height / h;
            float scaleX = width / w;
            PointF offset;
            SizeF crop;
            float size;

            if (scaleX >= scaleY) {
                size = h * (w / width);
                offset = new PointF (0.0f, h / 2.0f - size / 2.0f);
                crop = new SizeF (w, size);
            } else {
                size = w * (h / height);
                offset = new PointF (w / 2.0f - size / 2.0f, 0.0f);
                crop = new SizeF (size, h);
            }

            // Crop the image and flip it to the correct orientation (otherwise it will be upside down)
            ctx.ScaleCTM (1.0f, -1.0f);
            using (var copy = cg.WithImageInRect (new RectangleF (offset, crop))) {
                ctx.DrawImage (new RectangleF (0.0f, 0.0f, width, -height), copy);
            }
        } else {
            image.Draw (new RectangleF (0.0f, 0.0f, width, height));
        }

        UIImage scaled = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();

        return scaled;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid it doesen't answer my question regarding the cropping region - the desired outcome is a cropping region that overlays the image, which can be used to visualize the new image after the cropping has occured. But I may be able to use your cropping code, so a +1!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood your goal. I thought you wanted to crop.

Comment: I do, however the issue is I want a visual live preview of the cropping ;) - I already figured it out, and I will post my solution once it is ready. :)

Comment: Jeff, did you ever post your solution, i'm looking for the same thing.

Comment: @Jeff, how is the solution to this coming along... Same problem here

Comment: @kooldave98 source is lost, and forgot to post an update. There were other hickups as well, so it wasn't usable. Sorry fellas.

Comment: @Jeff, so did you give up on this entirely..? or did you design it out ? Basically, i would like to know whatever the solution you came up with is !

Comment: @kooldave98 it was supposed to be a component in an app we were making, but the app got discarded, so no real solution.